# A question about the boundary values of Dirichlet functions.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u_1$ and $u_2$ be two Dirichlet functions; hence both attain their maximum and minimum values on the boundary of the domain $D$ (let us call the boundary $B$).

My book says the following:

> Let $v=u_1-u_2$. Then $V$ also attains its minimum and maximum values on $B$ as a consequence of the minimum-maximum principle.

I don't see why this **has** to be correct. I feel $v$ may not attain its minimum and maximum values on $B$- it may attain them in the interior of $D$ itself.

Comment: I believe when you say dirichlet function, you say harmonic functions defined in $\overline{\Omega}$ ($\Omega$ a bounded smooth domain of $R^n$). The diference of harmonic functions is harmonic. Then by the maximum/minimum principle the diference function satisfies what your book says.

Comment: the only exception for the maximum/minimum principle is when the function is constant.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking: Unless you define what is to be  meant by "Dirichlet function", it is likely to be taken for its celebrated namesake http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html